# How to set up Checksum file in Firebase Server for Paytm Payment Gateway integration?

Tags: android, firebase, payment-gateway, checksum, paytm

I am working on an application that requires PayTM Payment Gateway integration. I am integrating PayTM, but while doing that I am facing a problem in setting up PayTM Checksum kit in server, which is the first step. Actually, in the example I am following, they have a XAMPP server and they are placing the Checksum KIT there itself. In my application, I have Firebase as backend database and index.js as the server. Can anyone direct me, regarding how and where to place the checksum kit when it comes to Firebase?

Comment: did you found any ? can you help me as i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Did anyone find solution to this question?? Do reply, it can help many people